# Doing do.call anova not working with extra arguments

Tags: r, function, anova, do.call

Hello I am working with these packages

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ISLR)
library(boot)
```

I created a list of various polynomial models and I would like run anova all the models together.

```
df<- Wage
degrees <-  seq(1,5)
Poly.fits <-  vector("list", length(degrees))
for (d in degrees){
  Poly.fits[[d]]<- lm(wage ~ poly(age,d), data = df)
}
```

This works

```
do.call("anova", Poly.fits)
```

This works as well

```
anova(Poly.fits[[1]], Poly.fits[[2]],  Poly.fits[[3]],  Poly.fits[[4]],  Poly.fits[[5]], test = "F")
```

I want to do this based on doing multiple arguments https://statisticsglobe.com/do-call-and-call-functions-in-r/ as found here

```
do.call("anova", list(Poly.fits, test = "F"))
```

But this does not work and leads to this error

*Error in UseMethod("anova") :
no applicable method for 'anova' applied to an object of class "list"*

Does anyone know how I could make this work if at all?

Comment: consider doing `do.call("anova", c(Poly.fits, test = "F"))`. Since you've loaded tidyverse, consider doing `invoke("anova", Poly.fits, test = "F")`

Comment: Yes the c functions makes it work thank you!

Comment: Also note that you are using `poly(,..raw =FALSE)` that means that you are obtaining orthogonalized matrix. Hence no need of the for-loop. Just a `summary(lm(wage ~ poly(age,5), data = df))` should work. The p-values obtained from the two functions should be exactly the same

Comment: Yes that is the case. I am doing it this way for a professor to showcase that. And I also need to do cross validation on each model as well. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Onyambu was correct

This works

```
do.call("anova", c(Poly.fits, test = "F"))
```

This works as well

```
invoke("anova", Poly.fits, test = "F")
```